# cannot use clojure/math.numeric-tower

Tags: clojure, libraries

So I want to use https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower how do I go about getting and using that library. There does not seem to be instruction on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attempting to use it from a [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) managed Clojure project, you would add `[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.2"]` to the `:dependencies` vector in the `project.clj` file. Then run the appropriate Leiningen command, like `lein repl`, if you wanted a repl, or `lein run` if your project is an application.